# insert() function doesn't add nodes to the binary search tree

Tags: javascript, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to make a binary search tree. If I start with an array my function makes a binary search tree out of that array (everything fine here). like for an array like `let a = [2,4,5,3,9,7,3,8,5];` the tree looks like the picture. my problem is with the insert() function. If I start with an empty array and add a node to it, it works. However, when I add a second node, that second node won't be added to my tree, and my tree is shown as having only 1 node in it (the root node). Here the snippet:

```
const Node = (data, left = null, right = null) => {
    return {data, left, right};
};

const Tree = array => {

    const remDupsAndSort = array => {
        const mergeSort = array => {
            if(array.length <= 1) return array;
            let leftArr = array.slice(0, array.length / 2);
            let rightArr = array.slice(array.length / 2);
            return merge(mergeSort(rightArr), mergeSort(leftArr))
        
        };
        
        const merge = (leftArr, rightArr) => {
            let sorted = [];
            while(leftArr.length && rightArr.length){
                if(leftArr[0] < rightArr[0]){
                    sorted.push(leftArr.shift());
                }else{
                    sorted.push(rightArr.shift());
                }
            };
            return [...sorted, ...leftArr, ...rightArr]
        };
        return mergeSort([... new Set(array)])
    };

    array = remDupsAndSort(array);

    const buildTree = (array, start, end) => {
        if(start > end) return null;
        let mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
        let node = Node(array[mid]);
        node.left = buildTree(array, start, mid - 1);
        node.right = buildTree(array, mid + 1, end);
        return node;
    };
    
    const insert = value => {
        if(!root) return root = Node(value);
        current = root;
        while(current){
            if(value < current){
                current = current.left
            }else{
                current = current.right
            }
        }
        current = Node(value)
        // if(!current){
        //     current = Node(value)
        // // }else{
        //     if(value < current){
        //         current.left = insert(value, current.left)
        //     }else{
        //         current.right = insert(value, current.right)
        //     }
        // }
        return root
        
    };
    
    
    const prettyPrint = (node = root, prefix = '', isLeft = true) => {
        if(node){
            if (node.right !== null) {
              prettyPrint(node.right, `${prefix}${isLeft ? '│   ' : '    '}`, false);
            }
            console.log(`${prefix}${isLeft ? '└── ' : '┌── '}${node.data}`);
            if (node.left !== null) {
              prettyPrint(node.left, `${prefix}${isLeft ? '    ' : '│   '}`, true);
            }
        }else{
            console.log(node)
        }
    }
    
    
    let root = buildTree(array, 0, array.length - 1);
    return {root, prettyPrint, insert}
};



let a = [2,4,5,3,9,7,3,8,5];
let b = [];
let c = [1,2,4,5,6,7]
let f = Tree(a)
let d = Tree(b)
let e = Tree(c)
d.insert(4)
// d.insert(8) ---> doesn't work
// d.prettyPrint()
// f.insert(1) ---> doesn't work
f.prettyPrint()
// e.prettyPrint()
// console.log(d.root)
```

if I run `d.prettyPrint()` I'll get `└── 4` just as expected. But if I run `d.insert(8)` after that 8 isn't added to the tree and the code returns `└── 4` again. To make matters more confusing if I `console.log(d.root)` it returns null even though my prettyPrint function returns `└── 4` as the root.

Clearly I expect the nodes be added to the tree. On one of my attempts I tried to write the code like this:

```
const insert = (value, current = root) => {
        if(!current){
            current = Node(value)
        }else{
            if(value < current){
                current.left = insert(value, current.left)
            }else{
                current.right = insert(value, current.right)
            }
        }
        return current
        
    };
```

even though I assigned `current = root` the code returned null for `d.insert(4)`

Comment: You've failed to declare a number of variables, but also aren't keeping an updated reference of `root` anywhere so it always just returns immediately on insert. It seems you are attempting to make a `Tree` class in which case the modern class syntax will be clearer. see: [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Comment: Added to that `if (value < current)` doesn't make sense as you actually want to compare to the current node's `data` property so `if (value < current.data)`

Comment: Here is a rough refactoring of your existing code into a Class [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6rs8z1a3/1/). It's not an answer as I don't have time and doesn't address many of the issues in your code, but it may point you in the right direction. You will want to refactor `Node` to be a class as well, and will need to deal with balancing the tree.

Comment: Any reason why you don't give feedback, nor mark answers as accepted, when people answer your previous questions?

Comment: @trincot I do give feedback, but I didn't know I was supposed to mark an answer as accepted. will do from now on. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are these issues in your `insert` function:

- `current` is implicitly defined as a global variable -- this wouldn't parse in strict mode. It should be declared as a local variable, using `let`
- The value is compared with a node object instead of with the data of that node. So `value < current` should be changed to `value < current.data`
- The assignment of the new node object to `current` -- after the loop -- will not mutate the tree. It merely assigns that object to that variable. Such assignment can never change the tree, just like `current = current.right` does not mutate the tree either. You need instead to assign the new node to either the `left` or `right` property of the *parent* of `current`. So this assignment should happen one step earlier.

Correction:

```
   const insert = value => {
        if(!root) return root = Node(value);
        let current = root; // Define with `let`
        while(current){
            if(value < current.data){ // Compare with the data, not the node
                // Mutate the parent node when inserting
                if (!current.left) return current.left = Node(value);
                current = current.left
            }else{
                if (!current.right) return current.right = Node(value);
                current = current.right
            }
        }
    };
```